# Java y Ajedrez: ¿Cómo hago para que la variable de la clase Posicion cambie tanto para la clase Ficha como para la clase Tablero?

Tags: java

Me encuentro ante un dilema; les mando un pequeño diseño de mis clases para que entiendan.

```
public class Ficha{
 boolean estaViva;
 Posicion posicion;
 Color color;

 enum Color{
  BLANCO, NEGRO;
 }
}

public class Posicion {
 boolean estaOcupada;
 int x;
 int y;
 Ficha ficha;
}

public class Tablero {
 static Posicion posicion[][] = new Posicion[8][8];
}
```

Ese es más o menos mi diseño de clases que hice, aunque es mucho más grande y hay más clases de por medio. Como podrán entender sólo puse los atributos de las clases y no los métodos o constructores porque no vienen tanto al tema y quería hacerla corta pero entendible.
Si hice bien en poner como `static` el atributo de posiciones quedará a criterio de ustedes.

Mi cuestión es la siguiente: Cuando yo recorro la matriz de posiciones y quiero mover una ficha, yo le pregunto al programa en qué posición está la pieza que quiero mover accediendo al atributo `posicion` de tipo `Posicion` que está en la clase `Ficha`. Pero cuando yo muevo una pieza yo accedo a la matriz de posiciones estática y hago los cambios ahi, porque se supone que esa matriz representa el tablero, y cada vez que cambio de posición en el tablero hago

```
Tablero.posicion[x][y] = new Posicion(x, y, ficha);
```

Pero la cuestión es que el atributo de posición en `Ficha` no cambia, se queda igual. La cuestión es: ¿Hice mal el diseño de clases?
Mi temporal solución fue poner el siguiente código en la clase `Ficha`:

```
public void mover(Posicion posicion){
 Tablero.posicion[x][y] = new Posicion(posicion.x, posicion.y, ficha);
 this.posicion = Tablero.posicion[x][y];
}
```

¿Hay alguna aproximación mejor?

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes pensado crear un solo tablero en el programa, los atributos `static` son una buena elección, pues cada objeto `Tablero` compartirá esos atributos, es decir, si crearas dos tableros con `new`, tendrán el mismo contenido dinámicamente.

Respecto al diseño, podrías tener una clase `Ajedrez` que debería de ser una 'composición' de fichas y un tablero, es decir, contener un atributo con un array de fichas `Ficha` y un tablero como atributo.

El prototipo sería:

```java
/** Clase "singleton" (una sola instancia) */
public class Ajedrez {
    static Tablero tablero;
    static Fichas[] fichas;
    ...
}
```

Teniendo en cuenta que en el constructor de la clase `Tablero` hayas inicializado todas las posiciones con sus respectivas fichas:

- El método `mover()` no debería de recibir un objeto `Posición` ni crear un objeto nuevo internamente cada vez, sino modificar el existente en la clase `Ficha` (De esta manera también cambiará en el `Tablero` si hiciste bien las inicializaciones en los constructores). Se supone que en los constructores ya has inicializado sus atributos, y que las posiciones de las fichas tienen las mismas referencias de objeto que en el tablero.
- Si te fijas bien, la variable `estaOcupada` debería ser un método que devuelva un `boolean`: `return this.ficha != null;`

```java
/** Sólo damos al método los índices del array de la posición 
  * nueva, así podemos pedir al tablero una nueva referencia de objeto 
  * y asignarla a la ficha. */
public void mover(int nuevaPosX, nuevaPosY){
    if(movimientoValido(nuevaPosX, nuevaPosY)) {
        // Se actualiza la antigua posición, pues ya no estará ocupada.
        posicion.estaOcupada = false; // Variable redundante.
        posicion.ficha = null; // Vaciamos.

        // La referencia "posicion" ahora apunta a otro objeto de la 
        // clase Tablero.
        posicion = Tablero.posicion[nuevaPosX][nuevaPosY];

        // Se actualizan las propiedades de la posición.
        posicion.estaOcupada = true;
        posicion.ficha = this;
   }
}
```

Para mover una ficha sería:

```java
...main() {
     ...
     int nuevaPosX = 4;
     int nuevaPosY = 2;
     ficha.mover(nuevaPosX, nuevaPosY);
     ...
}
```

Comment: Te agradezco la respuesta, y si bien comparto tu idea de hacer static un conjunto de fichas en la clase Tablero me encuentro ante otro problema. Quizas me adelante al limitar la cantidad de informacion sobre mis clases.

Las fichas están en la clase Jugador como atributos.
Hay una clase ajedrez pero se encarga de cosas genericas sobre el juego, como la inclusion de dos jugadores, aunque por otro lado en la clase Ajedréz podría haber creado un objeto de tablero, pero lo puse static por una cuestion simple, considero que el Tablero es el mismo para todas las clases.

Comment: quizas para clarificar mas el tem,a te puedo compartir por GDrive el enlace a mi codigo de fuente asi lo ves mas claro?

Comment: Estaría mejor reestructurar tu pregunta para que sea de utilidad a otras personas. Y así puedo modificar la respuesta para que te funcione. Ponme el link de GDrive si no puedes de otra manera. Pero no quisiera que pierda sentido el post.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9JnVT5Op7xNVHFwOTRveWtQYWc

Comment: El método `iniciarJuego()` está vacío, y la clase `Peon` no  compila.

Comment: Aquí tienes el [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1QMuNPVwjyJQWVuT05EdUpFUWs) con las clases corregidas, para que veas que no estabas reutilizando las referencias de los objetos `Posición`. Ahora el Alfil se mueve.

Comment: ah, perdon por lo del Peon, todavía no le di funcionalidad completa a todas las clases, en cuanto al Alfil el algoritmo es basicamente hacer un binomio al cuadrado para que se iguale la diferencia entre Y y X validando el movimiento, pero tuve un par de problemas con el codigo por como podes ver... cuestiones de diseño. Iniciar juego esta pensado para hacer lo que indica el metodo, comenzar un juego nuevo, pero no termine todavia el codigo así que no le di una utilidad. gracias por el apoyo!

Comment: Entiendo, por eso no le dí mayor importancia. ¿Probaste las clases que modifiqué?

Comment: He corregido unos pequeños fallos que tenías. [LINKGDrive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1QMuNPVwjyJQWVuT05EdUpFUWs) .
 Estabas creando las posiciones de las fichas en [x_blanco][y_blanco] y en el tablero en [y_blanco][x_blanco], es decir, que como no compartían las referencias de Posicion tus objetos Ficha y Tablero, no coincidía lo que imprimías del tablero, con las posiciones reales de las fichas, que estaban totalmente al revés. Y aunque modificaras la posición de una ficha con una nueva referencia (new Position), nunca iba a cambiarse la ficha en el tablero.

Comment: Hola Brian. ¿Viste los link de GDrive que te dejé?¿Conseguiste aplicar la solución a las demás fichas?. Espero tu respuesta. Saludos.